# Markov Chains to Predict Weather States

Tags: r, matrix

This is my first question so I apologize if it is located in the wrong section or does not follow forum protocols.

I am currently working on developing a transition matrix for predictions of weather in Tampa, FL. I used weather.com's data to categorize four states, "rainy", "cloudy", "sunny", and "fair." My attached code used this transition matrix to simulate a sequence, but after running the sequence for 500 iterations, it is only around 64% accurate. I am not sure if this is due to an error in my code, or if the available data from weather.com is not up to par. I would appreciate any and all advice.

Data obtained from: https://weather.com/weather/monthly/l/USFL0481:1:US

Code:

```
transition.matrix <- c(0,0.04,0,0,0.25,0.764,0.4545,0.6923,0,0.08,0.2727,0.0769,0.75,0.116,0.2728,0.2308)
library("markovchain")
stateNames <- c("1", "2", "3", "4")
mcB <- new("markovchain", states = stateNames, transitionMatrix =
matrix(transition.matrix, nrow = 4))
truth <- c("2", "4", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2")
outs <- function() {
  markovchainSequence(7, mcB, t0 = sample(1:4, 1, prob = c(0.04, 0.72,0.11,0.13)))
}
outz <- replicate(500, outs())
(length(which(outz[,1:500] == truth) == TRUE))/(500*7)
```

Comment: Sounds like a cool/fun model, Amber! (Also, welcome to CV!) Weather, being a [canonically nonlinear dynamic system, is likewise canonically difficult to model](https://www.ecmwf.int/en/elibrary/16927-chaos-and-weather-prediction). While weather forecasting models are better than they used to be, there are still limits to prediction in such chaotic systems. When you write "64% accurate" is that w/r/t *actual forecasts* by your model, or w/r/t your training data set?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It is for actual forecasts by the model. I simulated a week of weather states 500 times and compared it to the first week of April (which was withheld from the training set). The 500 predictions were 64% accurate.

Comment: I might follow the link I sent. Weather modeling is nontrivial. :)

Comment: I apologize I did not realize it was a link. I agree that this model will not be of the highest accuracy due to the chaotic nature, and many parameters involved in predicting weather. Would it be fair to conclude that I did model it correctly (if for a different data set) but a Markov process is not suitable for predicting the weather states? I am doing a research project to investigate whether the commonly used example of weather in Markov chains would actually apply.

Comment: I think that "correct" or "incorrect" is too simplistic a frame: a models are false, some models are useful. Your simple Markov model looks useful for teaching some ideas (e.g., about assumptions of Markov processes and models, and about the limitations of this kind of model for weather forecasting), perhaps less useful for forecasting, although better than random chance :).

Comment: There have been some successes in using Markov chains to model two states [No rain (0) and Rain (1)] in "Mediterranean climates" during the rainy season, including San Francisco, central coast of Chile, and Tel Aviv. Incoming rain storms are seldom more than a couple of days 'thick' and weather patterns over water are a little simpler than over land (especially if mountains are involved). These factors tend to make the one-step dependence of MCs good enough for reasonable predictions. Sadly, in these climates it's hard to beat the forecast that tomorrow will be like today ("usually" OK).

Comment: So weather is/isn't a Markov process? as the weather of today is not SOLELY dependent on the weather of yesterday. My research project is in shambles. Any suggestions to salvage it? Or is my intel incorrect? (intel is me second guessing everything I'm doing along with http://www.columbia.edu/~ww2040/3106F13/final3106F13sols.pdf ). I just need to know if it is reasonable that I applied the process to weather to begin with. Thanks for any and all help! @BruceET

Comment: @Alexis Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Amber I think it is ***worthwhile*** to construct your model for several reasons (1) you can see what you get with the model (better than random prediction!), (2) you can see what you do not get with the model (nothing like the accuracy of professional 10-day weather forecasts), and (3) you get ideas about how you might address point (2) with a more sophisticated model (e.g., what happens if you build in a one-lag violation of the Markov assumption? What happens if your transition matrix is itself a dynamic function of observed variables? Etc. How can you build off what you already have?).

Comment: @Alexis What is a one-lag violation of the Markov assumption and how would it be applied if you don't mind me asking? I'm sorry I tried to do research online but I could not find anything revolving around the violation of the assumption.

Comment: The Markov assumption is that the state of the system at time $t$ depends only on the state at time $t-1$ and the transition matrix. A 1 lag violation of that would be a model where the state at time $t$ depends on the states at times $t-1$ and $t-2$ (plus some transition rule accounting for $t-2$): in other words you add *memory* (of a single lag) to the model. Anyway, you are starting to veer towards asking new questions: so ask a new question!

Comment: I am so sorry to bombard you! I really appreciate the assistance. That makes much more sense now and I will explore this option. Thank you kindly. @Alexis